# React Native - Is there a chart library that allows adding multiple representations of different types of data to a single chart?

Tags: react-native, charts

I'd like to find a charting library in React Native that lets me render a normal line chart, but then also add a few extra details to it, for example: two horizontal lines rendered across the entire chart (not just as labels), representing a lower and upper limit, or a vertical line representing the "current time" on a line chart of time-based data points.

It seems like every chart library for RN is restricted to just rendering multiple data sets as the same type of chart (ie: multiple lines on a line chart), or maybe I just dont know how they work well enough to do what I want to do?

Poor mock up of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [`react-native-svg-charts`](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts).
You can visit the examples package [`react-native-svg-charts-examples`](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples) for relevant samples.

Specifically, [this example](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/storybook/stories/extras.js) shows you how to draw a line chart with an embedded horizontal dashed line.
Code from the example is copied below ([MIT License](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts-examples/blob/master/LICENSE)):

```
import React from 'react'
import { LineChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import * as shape from 'd3-shape'
import { Circle, G, Line, Rect, Text } from 'react-native-svg'

class ExtrasExample extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {

        const data = [ 50, 10, 40, 95, -4, -24, 85, 91, 35, 53, -53, 24, 50, -20, -80 ]

        /**
         * Both below functions should preferably be their own React Components
         */

        const HorizontalLine = (({ y }) => (
            <Line
                key={ 'zero-axis' }
                x1={ '0%' }
                x2={ '100%' }
                y1={ y(50) }
                y2={ y(50) }
                stroke={ 'grey' }
                strokeDasharray={ [ 4, 8 ] }
                strokeWidth={ 2 }
            />
        ))

        const Tooltip = ({ x, y }) => (
            <G
                x={ x(5) - (75 / 2) }
                key={ 'tooltip' }
                onPress={ () => console.log('tooltip clicked') }
            >
                <G y={ 50 }>
                    <Rect
                        height={ 40 }
                        width={ 75 }
                        stroke={ 'grey' }
                        fill={ 'white' }
                        ry={ 10 }
                        rx={ 10 }
                    />
                    <Text
                        x={ 75 / 2 }
                        dy={ 20 }
                        alignmentBaseline={ 'middle' }
                        textAnchor={ 'middle' }
                        stroke={ 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }
                    >
                        { `${data[5]}ºC` }
                    </Text>
                </G>
                <G x={ 75 / 2 }>
                    <Line
                        y1={ 50 + 40 }
                        y2={ y(data[ 5 ]) }
                        stroke={ 'grey' }
                        strokeWidth={ 2 }
                    />
                    <Circle
                        cy={ y(data[ 5 ]) }
                        r={ 6 }
                        stroke={ 'rgb(134, 65, 244)' }
                        strokeWidth={ 2 }
                        fill={ 'white' }
                    />
                </G>
            </G>
        )

        return (
            <LineChart
                style={{ height: 200 }}
                data={ data }
                svg={{
                    stroke: 'rgb(134, 65, 244)',
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                }}
                contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
                curve={ shape.curveLinear }
            >
                <Grid/>
                <HorizontalLine/>
                <Tooltip/>
            </LineChart>
        )
    }

}

export default ExtrasExample
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the quick response!